# MySQL die(); not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im still new in this Web Developing and im learning along rob percival's video at the udemy.com and the first time I try database grabbing and inserting and such is MySQL and right know im learning how to retrieve data from the database and the one thing I can't get to work or wondering if this how it should have gone when im using `die();` command it is not exactly going to the way I wanted to go like in rob's video.

This is the code im using that is connected to my database and using the `die();` command.

{php code

```
$link = mysqli_connect("ocalhost", "examplebb", "password", "examplebb");

if (mysqli_connect_error()){
    die("could not connect to database");
}

echo "hello";
```

this is the error I get and it still show the could not connect to database but has warning on it.

> **Warning**: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in **/home/daltonnapala/public_html/mysql/index.php** on line **3**
>
> **Warning**: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in **/home/daltonnapala/public_html/mysql/index.php** on line **3**
> could not connect to database

Comment: **ocalhost** really? Also, look at the last 5 words of your post.

Comment: In addition to the comment and Answer you have already received, the reason you do not hit the die(); statement is because the error is occuring in the first line of code, before you can hit the if statement.  Therefore, you get the Warnings on your screen first.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @AbraCadaver comment, it's not a connection problem like a wrong password, it's the host "ocalhost" is not resolved (because it does not exist). Just put "localhost" instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you typed **olcalhost** trying to get an propositional error, you did it. The warnings may be suppressed in an production server with `display_errors` php directive turned off.

So, your die() is working properly.